# Google sheets - Value of a cell based on the value I input in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've seen a hundred questions with the same 'title', however I can't figure out the right answer for my problem (or maybe it gets too hard for me).

It's about a Dungeons & Dragons sheet I'm creating for me and my friends.
First a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/khmo43

What I would like is, when I input a number below 'Experience - Cell G2' (like 250), the output in cell F2 would be 1 (since a character is level 1 between 0-299 experience). However, when the experience becomes 300 or higher (between 300-900) the output should be come 2 in Cell F2.

How can I, in this case, automatically have the output in Cell F2 be determined by the value in G2. *(So like, IF G2 is between A and B, F2 = C).*

I'm extremely sorry if I asked a double question. I've been looking for ages.

Comment: Can you post a link to the sheet? ... Actually I have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually not to hard, one I had a chance to think about it. You want to use an index match with a search key as `1`.

From the docs,

`search_type: 1, the default, causes MATCH to assume that the range is sorted in ascending order and return the largest value less than or equal to search_key.`

Because your levels are going to be sorted (I assume) you can put in the min value needed for a character to advance E.g. 0xp is the min value for level 1, 200xp is the min amount needed for level 2, 500xp is the min amount needed for level 3, etc.

`=INDEX($E$2:$E$7, MATCH($A$2,$D$2:$D$7, 1))`

Good luck with the campaign!

[image: example]

Comment: Hello,

Thanks, seems to help!

However, I had to replace the ',' with ';' for it to work, otherwise it would present a parse error.